# ksoap2 android 1c different xml structure

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

ksoap2 generates xml like this

```
<?xml
    version="1.0"
    encoding="UTF-8"
    ?>
<env:Envelope>
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    <env:Body>
        <tns:GetListClient>
            xmlns:tns="http://www.spr.org"
            hello
            </tns:GetListClient>
        </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

But web-service 1c, excepts only such xml-structured files

```
<soap:Envelope>
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        <soap:Header/>
        <soap:Body>
            <m:GetListClient>
                xmlns:m="http://www.spr.org"
                <m:Param/>
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                </m:GetListClient>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
```

as you see the difference is in this params

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Android code

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("Celsius", "23");
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        Log.e("request", request.toString());

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope,headerProperty);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            resultString = response.toString();
            Log.e("requestDumpCelsius",androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            Log.e("responseDumpCelsius",androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resultString = null;
        }
        if(resultString!=null)
        return resultString;
}
```

it gives me such exception

```
03-04 12:17:53.723    3932-3945/eu.msdlab.postmobile W/System.err﹕ SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Ошибка разбора SOAP сообщения: неизвестный параметр. ' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@41bf3470
03-04 12:17:53.723    3932-3945/eu.msdlab.postmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:137)
03-04 12:17:53.723    3932-3945/eu.msdlab.postmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
03-04 12:17:53.723    3932-3945/eu.msdlab.postmobile W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
```

What i need is to change structure of xml file
but PropertyInfo allows me to add only one namespace

**The problem solved**
Seems like i used wrong properties

Comment: What is headerProperty ? SoapObjectCustom , show them? also use request.addProperty("Celsius", "23"); not (SoapObject soapObject=request.addProperty("Celsius", "23");)

Comment: i modified my code, sorry

Comment: What NAMESPACE you using? also try to remove  envelope.implicitTypes = true;

Comment: private static final String NAMESPACE = "Android"; removing implicitTypes didn't help
i took all action,method and namespace from wsdl xml-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understood your code ,this might be `NAMESPACE` Problem

Try using

```
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
```

If above don't work then

```
private static String NAMESPACE = "xmlns:m="http://www.spr.org"";
```

If above both not work for you then please post **WSDL**

Comment: sorry, i watched wsdl file attentively and realised that i needed to use other properties and it finally worked) thanks for trying to help